# WordPress Custom comments form for registered users

Tags: wordpress, forms, comments

I want to modify the default comments form with two fields: "Comment" and "Name".

Then I need this "Name" appears at the list of comments on pages.

I need this only for registered or logged in users. I don't want appears the user name. I need the content of "Name" field instead.

How can I do this?

Best.

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles about what you need in the internet right now. Just Google something like "wordpress comment template" or other phrases.
But to give you a possible way to archive your changes:

#### Edit comment form:

Normally you have the fields "author", "email" and "url" in the comment form beside the comment itself. You can change the default display of input fields when you use the filter "comment_form_default_fields" in *functions.php* and disable the not used fields "email" and "url".

So just write your own function in *functions.php* and add it to the filter as below:

```
function your_comment_form_fields($fields){
    $fields['email'] = '';  //remove default email input
    $fields['url'] = '';  //remove default url input
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','your_comment_form_fields');
```

This will work globally.

#### Edit who can see comments:

To restrict the users who can see the comments you need to overwrite the default comments.php in your template. Just create a *comments.php* in your theme folder. For example, I use the default example from the WordPress Codex for [comments](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comments/#another-comments-php-example) and add an if statement before processing the part that displays the comment content. If the `is_user_logged_in()` function not returns true, there will displayed nothing. You can further change other parts of the comment template too.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains comments and the comment form.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and the visitor has not yet
 * entered the password we will return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() || !is_user_logged_in() )
    return;
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
            printf( _nx( 'One thought on "%2$s"', '%1$s thoughts on "%2$s"', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'twentythirteen' ),
                number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'short_ping'  => true,
                'avatar_size' => 74,
            ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php
        // Are there comments to navigate through?
        if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
            ?>
            <nav class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
                <h1 class="screen-reader-text section-heading"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h1>
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
            </nav><!-- .comment-navigation -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation ?>

        <?php if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
            <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'twentythirteen' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: You're right, i have explain my thoughts about it in an example for now.